# "Correct" chain in en very small blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

First, this question may have been partly answered [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47086/latest-block-of-multiple-mining-nodes) but what I will ask is very specific.

I have a chain with 3 nodes (A, B and C), all are mining.

A mines the block 1000 and synchronizes with C but not with B.
B ALSO mines the block 1000 and synchronizes with C but not with A.
They mine this block at the very same time.

A and B have the exact same chain from block 0 to block 999.

> How will react C? How can it determine what block is the correct one? (as the chain is the exact same length for both A and B)

EDIT: The possible duplicate is true, but the accepted answer is also valid, even though it is not going into the details, for those interested, go [THERE](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/314/what-is-ghost-and-what-is-its-relationship-to-frontier-and-casper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This results in a temporary network split until resolved.

The network splits and accepts both transactions temporarily. There is now essentially a Team A and Team B. The next mined block will determine which block will be turned into an [orphan](https://blockchain.info/orphaned-blocks) or [uncle](https://etherscan.io/uncles) block.

If Team A, or anyone connected to team A mines the next block, Team B's 1000 block becomes an orphan/uncle.

If Team B, or anyone connected to team B mines the next block, Team B's 1000 block becomes an orphan/uncle.

If C mines the next block, the 1000 block chosen be whichever team receives the broadcast of C's newly mined block first.

How each blockchain handles an orphaned block slightly differs based on whatever coding consensus was created for this scenario.

Please note, that this only applies if for some reason, A and B were trying to solve the same block of transaction data with the same exact difficulty.